# include user ID in session

Tags: php, html, sql, authentication, session

Currently my php login form will only carry acrocss the username on the session, I want this to carry across the user id (automatically created when the user registers).

As shown below I have included the user_id but it is not displaying on my webpage, the username is however.

Just wondering if anyone can help me with this? (I'm new to PHP)

Login process:

```
require_once('connection.php');
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
       if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['PWORD']))
       {
            header("location:login.php?Empty= Please Fill in the Blanks");
       }
       else
       {
            $query="select * from users where username='".$_POST['username']."' and PWORD='".$_POST['PWORD']."'";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $_SESSION['User']=$_POST['username'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                header("location:../manage_event.php");
            }
            else
            {
                header("location:login.php?Invalid= Please Enter Correct User Name and Password ");
            }
       }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not Working Now Guys';
    }
```

Session on next page:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['User']) || isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    echo ' Welcome ' . $_SESSION['User'].'<br/>';
    echo ' User ID ' . $_SESSION['user_id'].'<br/>';

}
else
{
    header("location:login/login.php");
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please check this to fix your issues: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/SQL_Injection_Attacks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though your security is questionable, i’ll answer your question anyway. As stated in another response you aren’t assigning your variables the right way. See an example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

The following code will fix your problems contrary to the other solution:

```
$query="select * from users where username='".$_POST['username']."' and PWORD='".$_POST['PWORD']."'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
/* fetch associative array */

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $_SESSION['User']=$_POST['username'];

        $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];     

        header("location:../manage_event.php");
    }     
}else {
            header("location:login.php?Invalid= Please Enter Correct User Name and Password ");
        }
   }
```

Make sure to replace this code with your old fetching code block. Thus in the first ‘else’ clause.

Comment: What is the problem with this answet?

Comment: Amazing thank you, this worked for me! I know the security isnt brillient, im helping a friend with a uni asignment.

Answer (score -2):

How about assigning the fetched result to `$row`:

```
$query="select * from users where username='".$_POST['username']."' and PWORD='".$_POST['PWORD']."'";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $_SESSION['User']=$_POST['username'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
```